# NSString with wrong characters when using UTF-8

Tags: objective-c, ios, encoding, utf-8, nsstring

I get data from a UTF-8 encoded XML file, and I want to display every element in a UITableView .
I want my cells to have the same size and display the 2 first text lines with the most data possible so I tried to remove the carriage returns.

In my cellForRow method I changed this :

```
[[myCell textLabel] setText:data];
```

By :

```
[[myCell textLabel] setText:[self correctData:data]];
```

Here is my correctData method :

```
- (NSString *) correctData : (NSString *) str
{
    NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < [str length] ; i++)
    {
        char car = [str characterAtIndex:i];
        if(car != 10 && car != 13) 
           [res appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",car]];
    }
    return res;
}
```

And this correctly removes the carriage returns, but it also alters the UTF-8 chars. For example, a bit of the initial string (str) :

> Diplômé(e) d'Etat

And with this function it becomes :

> DiplÙmÈ(e) d'Etat

What should I do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSString` works with `unichar` characters that are stored on 16bits whereas `char` is only 8bits long. Converting an `unichar` to a `char` will alter all characters with a code point above `U+00FF`.

You can solve this issue by replacing `char` with `unichar` and `%c` with `%C`.

**Edit:** But that's not really efficient. You may better use regular expressions to replace all newline characters in once:

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\r\n]+"
                                     withString:@""
                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

Comment: Amazing, that was so easy. Thanks a lot !